# how to solve undefind variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

i'm getting undefind variable error how to fix the error please
Undefined variable $expiredMaterials (View: C:\Users\Fatima\Desktop\PFE\Gpi_projet\resources\views\materiels_expires.blade.php

here is my code :

```
            @foreach($expiredMaterials as $material)
            <tr>
                <td class="id">{{ $material->id }}</td>
                <td class="type">{{ $material->type }}</td>
                <td class="série">{{ $material->série }}</td>
                <td class="marque">{{ $material->marque }}</td>
                <td class="réfference">{{ $material->réfference }}</td>
                <td class="service">{{ $material->service }}</td>
                <td class="date">{{ $material->date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
                <td class="date">{{ $material->expires_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
                <td class="status">{{ $material->status }}</td>
                <td class=" text-center">
                    <a class="m-r-15 text-muted update" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$value->id.'" data-target="#update">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: #2196f3"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ url('form/delete'.$value->id) }}" onclick="return confirm('Voulez-vous le supprimé?')">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red;"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

and this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Matériels;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use DB;

class MaterielsController extends Controller
{
   

    public function index()
{
    $expiredMaterials = Matériels::expired()->get();
    return view('materiels_expires', compact('expiredMaterials'));
}


    public function report(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            return redirect()->route('/');
        }
    
        $fromdate = $request->fromdate;
        $todate = $request->todate;
        $name = $request->name;
    
        $data = DB::table('Matériels')
            ->where('date', '>=', $fromdate . ' 00:00:00')
            ->where('date', '<=', $todate . ' 23:59:59')
            ->where('série', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
            ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
            ->get();
    
        $latestEntry = Matériels::latest()->first();
    
        return view('materiels_expires', compact('data', 'latestEntry'));
    }
}
```

another controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Matériels;
use Auth;
use DB;


class ReportController extends Controller
{
    // report
    public function report(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            return redirect()->route('/');
        }
    
        $fromdate = $request->fromdate;
        $todate = $request->todate;
        $name = $request->name;
    
        $data = DB::table('Matériels')
            ->where('date', '>=', $fromdate . ' 00:00:00')
            ->where('date', '<=', $todate . ' 23:59:59')
            ->where('série', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
            ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
            ->get();
    
        $latestEntry = Matériels::latest()->first();
    
        return view('report.report', compact('data', 'latestEntry'));
    }
    
}
```

my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Matériels extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        'expire' => 'datetime',
    'dis' => 'datetime'
    ];

    protected $table = 'Matériels';
    
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'type',
        'série',
        'marque',
        'réfference',
        'service',
        'status',
        'dis',
        'expire',
    ];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->expire = Carbon::parse(request()->input('expire'));
        });
    
        static::updating(function ($model) {
            if ($model->expire->isPast()) {
                $model->status = 'expiré';
                $model->save();
            }
        });
    }
    
    

    public function scopeExpired($query)
    {
        return $query->whereNotNull('expires_at')
                     ->where('expires_at', '<=', now())
                     ->where('status', '=', 'expiré');
    }
}
```

i'm trying to diplay a list of records entered by the user in an html table and these records have an expiration datetime when they are expired they are displayed in another section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables must be passed to the view like this:

```
return view('view', ['variableName' => 'variableValue']);
```

So in your case, you will need to write your return like so:

```
return view('materiels_expires', ['expiredMaterials' => compact('expiredMaterials')]);
```

Then you should be able to access `$expiredMaterials` in your view.

Comment: i tried this but didn't work

Comment: i solved the problem , i found that i used the same name for two routes